# Algorithmic quantifier elimination over p-adic fields

Tags: lo.logic, symbolic-computation

It is known that the first-order theory of p-adic fields is decidable, and that the p-adics admit elimination of quantifiers. What is the state of the art in algorithmic aspects of quantifier elimination over p-adic fields? Are there implementations of such  algorithms?